# java.lang.NullPointerException (SMS)

Tags: java

I created this program server and client to send sms via bluetooth and i got stuck with this problem my client works perfectly and this one to but when I'm running this file and press the but I get null point exception. I will appreciate your help.

```
                LocalDevice.getLocalDevice().setDiscoverable(DiscoveryAgent.GIAC);
```

## Error message

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at SMS_SERVER.jButton2ActionPerformed(SMS_SERVER.java:267)
        at SMS_SERVER.access$000(SMS_SERVER.java:27)
        at SMS_SERVER$1.actionPerformed(SMS_SERVER.java:101)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1995)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2318)
        at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:387)
        at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:242)
        at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:236)
        at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6289)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3267)
        at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6054)
        at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2041)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4652)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2099)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4482)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4577)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4238)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4168)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2085)
        at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2478)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4482)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:644)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:85)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:603)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:601)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:87)
        at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:98)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:617)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:615)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:87)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:614)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:269)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:184)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:174)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:169)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
```

Comment: What does the stacktrace tell you? The class, method and line number. Take it from there.

Comment: It would really help if you marked the line where the error occured, .e.g. 267. You could also turn on your brain and ask yourself, what value used at this line could possibly be null.

Comment: What's exactly on line 267 of `SMS_SERVER.java`?

Answer (score 1):

Follow Anothem's suggestion. If you're using jsr82, that's only the API. It is expected that developers do their own implementations.

Alternatively, you could download the Bluecove implementation binaries.

Answer (score 0):

If the line above is the one you encounter the exception on, check if LocalDevice.getLocalDevice() actually returns what you expect. If it doesn't, that's your problem.

Answer (score -4):

Try to put a new instance in your call of

`public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {`

-> `public void actionPerformed(new java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {`

let me know

Bye

Comment: This won't compile, and makes no sense.

Comment: Hello thank you for your reply I did try this didn't work can you please help me.